# Comparing two strings in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

I need to compare two strings
in excel and determine if they 
are equal, the strings are in adjacent
cells. For example, given:

```
apple   apple
water   water
pear    carrot
apple   water
dog     dog
pear    carrot
Apple   apple
```

the formula on the third column should give me:

```
true
true
false
false
true
false
false
```

Any help appreciated,
Ted

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use the built in `exact()` function which is `exact`-ly for this purpose:

```
=exact(A1, B1)
```

It will return true if the strings are identical.

Comment: I never noticed that equals was case insensitve before. Thanks.

Answer (score 29):

If case in your third column result is not important, `=A1=B1`.
If case in your result does matter, `=IF(A1=B1,"true","false")`.

This comparison (=A1=B1) is slightly different than the exact comparison since case sensitivity of the characters is not compared. The exact function also compares the character case. If you need case sensitivity checked and specify your own results, use `=IF(EXACT(A1,B1),"true","false")`.