# Excel - compare names in two cells in different order

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2003, cells

I need to compare the following

```
Cell 1         John Peter henderson                          
Cell 2         peter John Henderson                
Result         Match

Cell 1         Anne jolie beuhler             
Cell 2         Jolie Anne
Result         NO MATCH

Cell 1         Kate spade lee
Cell 2         susan kate spade
Result         NO MATCH
```

I need a perfect match for the name in any order. This is the code so far:

```
function allIn(str1, str2) 
' check whether all elements of str1 occur in str2 
' and vice versa 
Dim l1, l2, ii As Integer 
Dim isfound As Boolean 
isfound = True 
l1 = Len(str1) 
l2 = Len(str2) 

If l1 < l2 Then ' look for all the elements of str1 in str2 

For ii = 1 To l1 

If InStr(1, str2, Mid(str1, ii, 1), vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then 
    isfound = False 
Exit For 
End If 
Next ii 
Else ' look for all the elements of str2 in str1 

For ii = 1 To l2

If InStr(1, str1, Mid(str2, ii, 1), vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then 
isfound = False 
Exit For 
End If 
Next ii 
End If 
allIn = isfound 
End Function
```

Comment: Please define "a perfect match"

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Possible duplicate of [comparing two strings in excel?](http://superuser.com/questions/284022/comparing-two-strings-in-excel). Or does this have to be done using VBa, as per your tags?

Comment: I'm afraid VBA is needed, @Dave. Strangely enough, Excel is not too good with splitting strings, which is the start of any solution, I guess.

Comment: Can you post the code you've done and then we can see where it is going wrong. In theory, you take the value of each cell, split it to an array and compare each string at a time! Then if any are false, break out of the loop and return false.

Comment: Function allIn(str1, str2)
' check whether all elements of str1 occur in str2
' and vice versa
Dim l1, l2, ii As Integer
Dim isfound As Boolean

isfound = True

l1 = Len(str1)
l2 = Len(str2)

If l1 < l2 Then
' look for all the elements of str1 in str2
  For ii = 1 To l1
    If InStr(1, str2, Mid(str1, ii, 1), vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then
      isfound = False
      Exit For
    End If
  Next ii
Else
' look for all the elements of str2 in str1
  For ii = 1 To l2

Comment: If InStr(1, str1, Mid(str2, ii, 1), vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then
      isfound = False
      Exit For
    End If
  Next ii
End If
allIn = isfound
End Function

Comment: sorry there are character constraints so I actually split it up to 2

Comment: I updated your post, but please do it yourself in future. Don't provide more detail in comments as this is hard for others to read. Feel free to [edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/637645/edit) in case I've made any errors

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I've done VBa and I can not test this, but, this should give you a good start if it doesn't compile or even work exactly as required.

```
' check whether all elements of str1 occur in str2
' and vice versa.
Function allIn(str1, str2) As Boolean

'first thing to check is if the 2 strings are the same length, if they're not then we know they are different
If Len(str1) <> Len(str2) Then
    allIn = False
End If

Dim isfound As Boolean
isfound = True

'Get the 1st string as array (split by white space)
Dim s1() As String
s1() = Split(str1)

'iterate through each array, word at a time
For Each element In s1

    If Not InStr(str2, element) Then
        isfound = False
    End If

'if it wasn't found, we can exit the loop immediately (no point finishing the test as it's already failed)
If (isfound = False) Then
    Exit For
End If

Next element

allIn = isfound
End Function
```

I have a few concerns about this code though, such as what happens if an extra piece of white space was at the start or tail of the str1 or str2... However, this should do what your question is asking (again, not tested)

You may need to ensure that the string is always trimmed and or lower case when doing the comparison etc, not sure how it works in VBa.

Comment: It has a syntax error

Comment: Function allIn(str1, str2) As Boolean 

on this line

Comment: @gwen, Updated, but still not tested